# Luma theme home page content not showing

Tags: magento-2.1, luma-theme

I have downloaded Magento CE 2.1.8 and installed it on a local system, now when I access the home url Luma theme shows a page like this:

[image]

Instead if something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Magento provides two types of [source](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download)

1) Full Release (ZIP with no sample data)

2) Full Release with Sample Data (ZIP with sample data)

Make sure which source you have downloaded

However you can deploy sample data via command

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

Make sure you clean your cache after process

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
rm -rf <your magento root dir>/var/*
find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because sample data is missing in your new Magento instance. Install sample data and you are good to go.

You can install sample data mainly in two ways.

- Via composer
- Via git repository.

Composer way is highly recommended.

For more information, please go thorugh the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-magento.html